# OpenAI Error: 400 while using AzureCognitive search as retriever

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

I have combined AzureOpenAI with Azure Cognitive search as retriever, here's the code:

```py
from langchain.retrievers import AzureCognitiveSearchRetriever

os.environ["AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME"] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
os.environ["AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"] ="xxxxxxxx"
os.environ["AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_API_KEY"] ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

retriever = AzureCognitiveSearchRetriever(content_key="content")
retriever.get_relevant_documents("what did george lucas say about star wars?")
```

But I get: `Error in search request: <Response [400]`

I tried changing the parameters but, I could not find the solution

Comment: 400 responses returned when there's an error in the request URI, headers, or body as Azure Cognitive Search stated. Can you please share the full error response with the message?